# Blueimp Bootstrap file upload - detecting files not yet uploaded

Tags: jquery, file-upload, twitter-bootstrap, blueimp

I'm using the blueimp jQuery File Uploader and it works fine, no problems whatsoever. However, I'm using it on a page that is also submitted, so I want to ensure that all selected images have been uploaded before the page is submitted.

I see from the blueimp wiki, that the way to get feedback on files added/uploaded/done is via the bind() method, which works fine. And according to the blueimp wiki the various bind options are as follows:

```
$('#fileupload')
.bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
.bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
.bind('fileuploadsend', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
.bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
.bind('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
.bind('fileuploadalways', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
.bind('fileuploadprogress', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
.bind('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
.bind('fileuploadstart', function (e) {/* ... */})
.bind('fileuploadstop', function (e) {/* ... */})
.bind('fileuploadchange', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
.bind('fileuploadpaste', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
.bind('fileuploaddrop', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
.bind('fileuploaddragover', function (e) {/* ... */});
```

From this I can probably figure out when a file is added, and when it has been uploaded. However I'm unable to figure out if a file is deleted before being uploaded. The wiki suggests using other bindings as follows:

```
Note: Adding additional event listeners via bind method is the preferred option to preserve callback settings by the jQuery File Upload UI version.
```

But the link indicated there in the wiki is a broken link.

Does anybody have any idea how to detect when a file is removed? Will I have to do a less elegant jQuery selector approach, or is there a better way? This is surely not an uncommon use case where file uploads are concerned?

Answer (score 0):

If the link on the wiki is broken, report the issue on https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues